# Why boundaries oriented this way for Stokes's Theorem?

Tags: proof-explanation, stokes-theorem, orientation

[image]

In the proof above, why do the boundary curves of $ S_1$. and $ S_2$ need to be oriented in opposite directions? Why are the boundary curves of each respective hemisphere oriented in opposite directions? How do you prove the flux of the curl or the two hemispheres are equal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to prove that the integral of the curls on the two hemispheres is equal. That is an outcome of this problem, not an intermediate step needed to prove the result.

The problem proceeds by first using Stokes' theorem to show that the the two surface integrals are in fact, equal to the two line integrals on the curve $C$ of F. Then the solution is pointing out that regardless of what value $F$ takes on that curve, one of the terms is the negative of that other because they are the same function integrated over the same curve, just in an opposite direction. Hence they cancel.

To answer your first question about the boundary curves are oriented in opposite directions, use the [right hand thumb rule](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-hand_rule) for the orientation (look at the figure in the section "a rotating body" to see how to hold your hand - if thumb is along the normal, the direction of your fingers gives the direction of the boundary). The outward normal in the upper hemisphere points up, but in the lower it points down, so the boundaries are oriented in the opposite directions. Also are this [Khan Academy video](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/multivariable-calculus/greens-theorem-and-stokes-theorem/stokes-theorem/v/orientation-and-stokes) explaining this.

Comment: I’m confused on how the flux of the curl of. Sphere is 0. Spheres have no boundary so the curl of the flux on a sphere is 0?

Comment: The solution you pasted explains that. Spheres have NJ boundaries. So we cut the sphere into two halves, each of which does have a boundary (the same curve). The flux of the curve is NOT zero. As I explain in the answer, just the integral of the flux in each half is found to be equal to the one in the other half.  Read through the proof carefully, and use my answer for explanation as you read and you will see it.

Comment: I think the confusion is that you are mistaken about the direction of the proof.  The zero on the end does not come from knowing the curl. It is the other way around. Zero is derived from the boundaries. So we can conclude something about the *integral* of the curl over the sphere (zero) even though we cannot say that the curl itself is zero.

Answer (score 1):

The boundary of any manifold is always orientable. We may choose a normal vector pointing into the interior of the manifold (or alternatively one pointing out). For any point on the equator, the normal vector pointing into the interior of the upper hemisphere is opposite the one pointing into the lower hemisphere.

Comment: Why aren't both normal vectors in the same direction? Why is the flux of the curl of the sphere not two times the flux of the curl of a hemisphere?

Comment: An orientation on a manifold with boundary induces an orientation on the boundary, and this is the orientation that is required to make Stokes theorem hold. This is the orientation where each boundary's normal vector points into the interior. They can't be the same, because the interiors of the manifolds aren't the same. The interiors of the hemispheres are opposite, so the normal vectors and orientations are opposite.

Comment: A hemisphere has an orientation? But we can flip the latter hemisphere and superimpose the two hemispheres they’re the same thing

Comment: The oriented version of Stokes theorem requires the both manifold and its boundary to both be oriented compatibly. The orientations of the two hemispheres are the "same" (they are restrictions of the orientations of the whole sphere), as you observe. But you cannot stitch hemispheres together to make a sphere if they are superimposed lined up so their boundaries have same orientation. They have to be lined with their boundaries having opposite orientation.